# Como conseguir este botón?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Quería que mi app, en el apartado de Cuentas del móvil al seleccionar una cuenta salga este button, debe ser una imagebutton :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo que realiza es una sincronización manual de la cuenta en la que está. 
He visto manuales de que se tiene que realizar con el archivo xml preference.xml pero al añadírselo me sale fuera de las cuentas.

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:title="Sincroniza" android:key="sincronizacion" android:text="sdsd"/>
```

```
public class PreferenceAccounts extends PreferenceActivity{

Account account;
public static final String AUTHORITY= "jp.example";
final Bundle extras = new Bundle(1);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.account_preference);

    Preference button = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("sincronizacion");
    if(button != null){
        button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, false);
                params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
                ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, extras);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pedro, en la imagen solo veo texto pero no un botón.

Comment: Es un texto que pulsas y sincroniza la app, aparte de que el texto actualiza la fecha y hora. @Jorgesys